# Passing variable from ForEach to addEventListener

Tags: javascript, variables, addeventlistener

I'm trying to figure out how to pass a variable from my `forEach` loop into the `addEventListener('scroll')` method.

Here is a fiddle :

```js
(function parallax() {
    let p = document.querySelectorAll('.js-parallax'),
        i = 0,
        m

    p.forEach(function (el, m) {  
        i % 2 == 0 ? m = 1 : m = 2
        i++

        console.log('m: ' + m + ' and i: ' + i)

        document.addEventListener('scroll', function(m) {
            console.log('And now m: ' + m + ' and i: ' + i)
        })
    });
})()
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="js-parallax"></div>
  <div class="js-parallax"></div>
  <div class="js-parallax"></div>
  <div class="js-parallax"></div>
  <div class="js-parallax"></div>
</body>
```

The idea is to work with a custom Parallax script where `m` is a multiplier and is different for one out of two item in `p`.
I use first `i`, if it's odd, `m = 1` and if it's even `m = 2`.

You'll see in the snippet console, `m` is fairly recognized within the loop but outside `addEventListener()`. Second console log output `m = [object Event]`. From here I'm kind of stuck.

Any clue? Thanks in advance,

A.

Comment: The first `console.log()` works fine, the second within `addEventListener('scroll')` does not. It output `m = [object Event]`. I'm trying to output m value for each element on scroll

Comment: Question, why are you adding multiple event on same element in loop? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I think you got confused a bit.. You add listeners to a `document` event, in a `forEach` loop that iterates over elements

Comment: @Rajesh I generate multiple SVG elements (number and size are random). With this script, I try to get all SVG elements, and on scroll, apply them a `transform: translateY()` of `10px * m` where `m` is different for 1 out of 2

Comment: Because the `m`  in the event listener is the first parameter of that callback, and as of that the event. That `m`  has nothing to do with `m` in this stamement   `i % 2 == 0 ? m = 1 : m = 2`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @all for your answers.

So I reconsidered my script, I was actually inverting my logic.
Best may is to use `document.addEventListener('scroll')` and the use `forEach` function. And it works like a charm.

```
(function parallax() {
    let p = document.querySelectorAll('.js-parallax'),
        i = 0,
        m

    document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        p.forEach((el, m) => {  
            i % 2 == 0 ? m = 1 : m = 2
            i++

            console.log('m: ' + m + ' and i: ' + i)
        });
    })
})()
```

Issue can be closed! Thanks you all :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't send parameters into the listener function.
The parameter for listener is only one and always Event object.

Instead, you can add property the target element. 
Like below

```
p.forEach(function(el, m) {
    i % 2 == 0 ? m = 1 : m = 2
    i++
    el.multiplier = m;
```

and then,
you can use the property in the listener function.

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
       console.log(e.target.multiplier);
    })
```

Comment: There is no need to assign the value to `el`. Because of the way how closures it would be sufficent to just rename the `m`  parameter of the event callback to form `m`  to ` evt`, after that the ` m`  out the outer scope can be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

- You're printing the event param when the scroll's event is triggered.
- You're assigning the result of `i` to the only scroll event, I mean, you’re overriding the event `scroll` in every loop.  Therefore , your scroll event will execute the logic with `i = 5`;

Look at this code snippet using the correct variable `m` and the correct event param.

```js
(function parallax() {
  let p = document.querySelectorAll('.js-parallax'),
    i = 0,
    m

  p.forEach(function(el, m) {
    i % 2 == 0 ? m = 1 : m = 2
    i++

    console.log('m: ' + m + ' and i: ' + i)

    document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
      console.log('And now event: ' + JSON.stringify(e) + ' - m: ' + m + ' and i: ' + i)
    })
  });
})()
```

```css
body {
  min-height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="js-parallax"></div>
  <div class="js-parallax"></div>
  <div class="js-parallax"></div>
  <div class="js-parallax"></div>
  <div class="js-parallax"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: He is adding the same event to document for every parallax element out there. There is nothing inside defining which parallax will be triggered or something. Maybe there is something to fix that ... issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `i` and `m` within the scope of `.forEach()` (`.map()` in this case) so that it is not overwritten. I also changed the `event` from `scroll` to `mousewheel` so you could see how the `Map` works. Just scroll the page by using your wheel instead of the scrollbar:

```js
(function parallax() {
  let p = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.js-parallax'))

  let map = new Map(p.map(function(el, i) {
    let m = i % 2 == 0 ? 1 : 2

    console.log('m: ' + m + ' and i: ' + i)

    return [el, { m, i }]
  }))

  document.addEventListener('mousewheel', function(event) {
    let el = event.target
    
    if (map.has(el)) {
      const { m, i } = map.get(el)

      console.log('And now m: ' + m + ' and i: ' + i)
    }
  })
})()
```

```css
:root {
  --console-height: 88px;
  --margin: 0.5em;
  --parallax-height: 100vh;
}

.js-parallax {
  height: calc(var(--parallax-height) - var(--margin) * 2 - var(--console-height));
  background-color: cyan;
  margin: var(--margin);
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: var(--console-height);
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: var(--console-height) !important;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="js-parallax"></div>
  <div class="js-parallax"></div>
  <div class="js-parallax"></div>
  <div class="js-parallax"></div>
  <div class="js-parallax"></div>
</body>
```